# How do I create efficient code for a toggle between two buttons in Javascript using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to toggle between two buttons efficiently using javascript and jQuery.

## Scope

When clicking on either Yes or No, the opposite button will get a `disabled` CSS class while the clicked button will get an `active` CSS class. A `var` will also be saved with a `true` `false` value that will be used later.

## html

```
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="yes">Yes</button>
  <button id="no">No</button>
</div>
```

## js

```
function bindButtons(){
  var buttons = $('#buttons button');

  buttons.on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    buttons.removeClass('selected');
    if($this.attr('id') == 'yes'){
      var el = $('#no'),
          val = true;
      $this.removeClass('disabled');
      $this.addClass('selected');
      el.addClass('disabled');
    }
    if($this.attr('id') == 'no'){
      var el = $('#yes'),
          val = false;
      $this.removeClass('disabled');
      $this.addClass('selected');
      el.addClass('disabled');
    }
    //do something with val
  })
}
bindButtons();
```

## jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RobertSheaO/Tjngw/2/

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to jsFiddle. Link only posts are [explicitly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) on Stack Exchange as your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future!

Comment: + what makes you think this is *hugely* inefficient? Have you seen this code impacting your UI responsiveness?

Comment: jQuery has a radiobutton option if that fits your needs. [jQuery Button](http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be OK as a replacement to your `bindButtons` function meat.

> #### EDIT
>
> Apparently, this should also work with more than one button. Late night coding as well. >*_*>

```
var buttons = $('#buttons button').on('click', function (e) {

    var $this = $(this).removeClass('disabled').addClass('selected'),
        el = buttons.not(this).addClass('disabled'),
        isYes = $this.is('#yes')
        ;

    // do something with isYes

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjngw/5/)

It's perfectly readable for me, but it might not be for you, so this might be better if you'd like:

```
var buttons = $('#buttons button').on('click', function (e) {

    var $this = $(this),
        el = buttons.not(this),
        isYes = $this.is('#yes')
        ;

    $this.removeClass('disabled');
    $this.addClass('selected');
    el.addClass('disabled');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the html5 data- attribute in your html for the answer and some jquery toggeling.

## html

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="yes" data-answer="true">Yes</button>
    <button id="no" data-answer="false">No</button>
</div>
```

Toggeling is easy using jQuery:

## Javascript

```
// Bind events to your buttons
var bindButtons = function(){

    $('#buttons').on('click', 'button', function( e ){

        e.preventDefault();

        $(this)
            .addClass('selected');
            .siblings()
            .removeClass('selected')
            .addClass('disabled');
    });

};

// Init binding
bindButtons();

// Get your answer
var answer = $('#buttons .selected').data('answer');
```

## Demo

[Try it on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/inowef/2).

Answer (score 1):

```
function bindButtons(){
  var buttons = $('#buttons button');

  buttons.on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    buttons.removeClass('selected').addClass('disabled');
    $this.addClass('selected').removeClass('disabled');

    switch ($this.attr('id')){
        case 'yes': 
            val = true;
            break;
        case 'no': 
            val = false;
            break;
    }
    //do something with val
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function bindButtons(){
  $('#buttons button').click(function(e){ 
    var thisObj = $(this);
    $('#buttons').removeClass('selected');
    thisObj.removeClass('disabled').addClass('selected').siblings().addClass('disabled');
    var val = thisObj.attr('id')=='yes' ? true : false;    
    //do something with val
  })
}
bindButtons();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tjngw/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like shortening:

```
$this.removeClass('disabled');
$this.addClass('selected');
```

to:

```
$this.removeClass('disabled').addClass('selected');
```

And probably change the second `if(){` to an `else{`

Apart from shortenings like that, unless this code is dragging the browser down (which is isn't) then there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps a little. I usually use jQuery's `.not()` with `$(this).`

```
$('#buttons button').click(function() {
    $('#buttons button').not($(this)).removeClass('enabled').addClass('disabled');
    $(this).removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled');

    var selected = $(this).attr('id'); // To use the id, or to use text use:
    var selected = $(this).text();  // No need for ids, grabs the text of element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
function bindButtons(){
  var buttons = $('#buttons button');

  buttons.on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var el = $this;
    var val = $this.attr('id') === 'yes';
    buttons.removeClass('selected disabled');
    $this.addClass('selected')
      .siblings('button').addClass('disabled');

    //do something with val
  })
}
```

It at least removes the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#buttons button").on('click', function(e) {
    $(".selected").removeClass('selected');

    var el;

    if($this.attr('id') == 'yes'){
        val = true;

        el = $("#no");
    } else {
        val = false;

        el = $("#yes");
    }

    $this.removeClass('disabled').addClass('selected');
    el.addClass('disabled');
});
```